# TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str In Python

Tags: python, range

I am new and trying my hands on python.
I wrote a program in python and when I execute I get errors. Can anyone please help me?

Program:

```
first = raw_input("Enter the first no:")
second = raw_input("Enter Second no:")
if first <= 0:
        print "Enter a valid number"
if second <= first:
        print "Sencond number should be greater than first"
for x in range(first,second):
        for i in range(2, i):
                if x % i == 0:
                        j = x/i
                        print x,  " is not a prime no"
                        print "%d = %d*%d" % (x, i, j)
                        break;
                else:
                        print x, " is not a prime number"
```

Input and error:

```
Enter the first no:1
Enter Second no:9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "today1.py", line 7, in <module>
    for x in range(first,second):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: well, from stdin you get strings, not numbers. You'll have to convert them. (`int()` comes to mind)

Answer (score 6):

raw_input() returns a string.

Try this code:

```
    first = int(raw_input("Enter the first no:"))
    second = int(raw_input("Enter Second no:"))
```

And are you sure, that `for i in range(2, i):` shouldn't be `for i in range(2, x):`?

Comment: Thanks Max, It worked. And yes, that would be x, not i. cheers. :)

Comment: Hey Max...I don't have that much reputation to like a post. So, I hope you understand. I am really thankful.